# Python truncate method size argument behavior

Tags: python, file

I am trying to update the content inside a file by replacing the content of the string and writing the updated content.

Now to do, I need to delete the older content and write back the updated one, so for this, I am using `truncate` method.

As per documentation of `truncate`

> file. truncate([size])
>
> size Optional. If the optional size argument is present, the file is
>   truncated to (at most) that size. The size defaults to the current
>   position.

**Now, I have got two cases which I am not able to comprehend what is going on?**

```
def fileIsWritingInBinary():
  with open("hello.txt", "r+") as f:
    fileContent = f.read()
    f.truncate(0) # used different size argument

    # update new content
    fileContent = fileContent.replace("World", "StackOverFlow")

    # write updated content
    f.write(fileContent)
```

The content which gets written in file `hello.txt` is in a different format i.e.

```
  4865 6c6c 6f00 0000 0000 0000 0048 656c
  6c6f 2c20 576f 726c 6421
```

But after making a change as described below it works perfectly i.e. add `f.seek(0)` before `truncate` call.

```
def fileIsWritingInBinary():
  with open("hello.txt", "r+") as f:
    fileContent = f.read()

    f.seek(0) // line added
    f.truncate()

    # update new content
    fileContent = fileContent.replace("World", "StackOverFlow")

    # write updated content
    f.write(fileContent)

    # hello.txt content
    # Hello, StackOverFlow!
```

Now the question is,

1. Why `truncate(0)` call was leading to file get written in the different format?
2. I have changed the size argument to from `0` to a different number but still, I was getting the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the documentation of [`truncate`](https://docs.python.org/library/io.html#io.IOBase.truncate) in the `io` module you see what's going on:

> Resize the stream to the given size in bytes (or the current position if size is not specified). **The current stream position isn’t changed**. This resizing can extend or reduce the current file size. In case of extension, the contents of the new file area depend on the platform (on most systems, additional bytes are zero-filled). The new file size is returned.

(Emphasis mine)

So even though you truncate the stream - you haven't changed the position in the stream (that's what `seek` does). How that is resolved when you `write` may depend on the OS (on my computer the first example worked!) But you can always let Python `tell` you the current position in the stream:

```
with open("hello.txt", "r+") as f:
    fileContent = f.read()
    print(f.tell())
    f.truncate(0)
    print(f.tell())
    f.seek(0)
    print(f.tell())

    # update new content
    fileContent = fileContent.replace("World", "StackOverFlow")

    # write updated content
    f.write(fileContent)
    print(f.tell())
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Any idea why `write` is OS dependent? or any article to learn more about the internal working of it.

Comment: Well the [`io`-module](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/master/Modules/_io) is written in C so it's likely that some C-functions behave differently on different OS (or depending on the compiler). If you need any detailed behaviour that's probably the best (but not necessarily understandable) ressource. :)